# Flexible sized underline

Tags: spacing, underline

I want to have a blank line followed by 5 check boxes, such that together they occupy the entire horizontal space available.

The current way I have "solved" this problem is:

```tex
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\framebox{\begin{minipage}{0.25\textwidth}
\underline{\hspace{0.77\textwidth}}\,$\square$ $\square$ $\square$ $\square$
\underline{\hspace{0.77\textwidth}}\,$\square$ $\square$ $\square$ $\square$
\underline{\hspace{0.77\textwidth}}\,$\square$ $\square$ $\square$ $\square$
\underline{\hspace{0.77\textwidth}}\,$\square$ $\square$ $\square$ $\square$
\end{minipage}}
\end{document}
```

Where `0.77` is just some number I found by a rather tedious binary search.  Now this is not great, if I adjust any parameter (number of squares, space between squares, size of the page, size of the enclosing box etc.) or add anything this number has to be recalculated.  I'd ideally like a way to say "Put 5 squares on the right and fill the remaining space with underline (plus some padding)".  But I've struggled to get this working.

Is there some way I can do this without having to rely on magic numbers?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I understand what you want to do, but could you use `\hrulefill` rather than `\underline`, e.g.: `\hrulefill\,$\square$ $\square$ $\square$ $\square$\\ `

Comment: @frabjous Yep looks like `\hrulefill` is the exact tool I was looking for.  Thanks.

Comment: There's also the [xhfill](https://ctan.org/pkg/xhfill?lang=en) package if you need some more flexibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others commented, `\hrulefill` is your friend, but you probably want to simplify your input and avoid doing repetitive and boring things (which are prone to error; indeed you talked about five boxes, but only typed four).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\checkboxes}{mmm}
 {% #1 is the width
  % #2 is number of lines
  % #3 is the number of check boxes
  \noindent
  \fbox
   {
    \begin{minipage}{ \dim_eval:n { #1 - 2\fboxsep - 2\fboxrule } }
    \ozaic_checkboxes:nn { #2 } { #3 }
    \end{minipage}
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \ozaic_checkboxes:nn
 {
  \prg_replicate:nn { #1 }
   { % lines
     \hrulefill \prg_replicate:nn { #2 } { \ $\square$ } \par
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\checkboxes{0.25\textwidth}{4}{5}

\bigskip

\checkboxes{0.5\textwidth}{3}{4}\checkboxes{0.5\textwidth}{3}{4}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see from the second example, the space occupied is *exactly* half of the text width.

Comment: I already had a bunch of loops to avoid repetition, I just removed them for the mwe since they required packages and just made things more complicated for the reader.  However it's neat to see your method since it's very divergent from mine.  I naturally used techniques I was comfortable with so it might benefit me and my code to copy a bit from this.

Comment: @SriotchilismO'Zaic Look, ma! No package! :-)

Comment: @SriotchilismO'Zaic note that `\hrulefill` creates the line at baseline but the question was about flexible sized *underline*. That is a reason why I suggest to use `\leaders` and `\vrule` directly with dimensions designed for underline position in my answer. It needs no package too, moreover it needs no expl3.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\leaders` TeX primitive:

```
\def\ulinefill{\noindent\null\leaders\vrule depth2.4pt height-2pt\hfill}

\begin{document}
\framebox{\begin{minipage}{0.7\textwidth}
\ulinefill\,$\square$ $\square$ $\square$ $\square$\break
\ulinefill\,$\square$ $\square$ $\square$ $\square$\break
\ulinefill\,$\square$ $\square$ $\square$ $\square$\break
\ulinefill\,$\square$ $\square$ $\square$ $\square$
\end{minipage}}
\end{document}
```